# Find four digit $abcd$ such that $ab \cdot cd = abcd$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I stumbled upon this problem and I can't seem to figure it out. It's an easy-looking problem and it goes like  this:

> Find the $4$-digit number $abcd$ such that if you multiply the two
>   $2$-digit numbers $ab$ and $cd$, you again get the $4$-digit number
>   $abcd$.

I started like this:

Let $x = 10a + b$ and $y = 10 c + d$, with $a,b,c,d \in \{0,\ldots, 9\}$. The problem is then reduced to: $x\cdot y = (10a + b)(10c+d) = 1000a + 100b + 10c + d$, with the latter being the $4$-digit number $abcd$.

Or equivalently, $$100ac + 10 ad + 10bc + bd = 1000a + 100b + 10 c + d.$$ Unfortunately, this reasoning doesn't get me very far. Any ideas?

Comment: so $bd + 10X = d + 10Y$ which means $(b-1)d \equiv 0 \pmod {10}$

Comment: The computer says that the only solution is 0000.

Comment: My Excel agrees with @MJD

Comment: For proper two-digit numbers, $ab\cdot cd$ is always quite far apart in absolute value from $abcd$: the closest is $10\cdot99 = 990$, which is $109$ away from $1099$. If one-digit numbers are allowed, then $1\cdot1$ is $10$ away from $11$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's impossible!

For $ab * cd = abcd$, $cd$ would need to be at least $100$

Comment: Nice, real smooth!

Comment: @Riley This is assuming we're dealing with a 'proper' 4-digit number of course, i.e. $a > 0$.

Comment: If $ab >0$ and $cd \ge 0$ we get $cd \ge 100$.  Don't see any definition of 4 digit and 2 digit that allow that.  So $ab = 0$ and $0*cd = cd$ so $cd = 0$.  So $(00)(00) = 0000$ is only solution.  At any rate, I'd assume "proper" is a reasonable assumption, as would I assume a,b,c,d are distinct.

Comment: @Bram28, I'm afraid I can't follow, why has $cd$ to be at least 100? You can easily reach a four digit number with 2 digit numbers? E.g. $50 \cdot 50 = 2500  \geq  1000$

Answer (score 2):

Take your equation
$$100ac + 10 ad + 10bc + bd = 1000a + 100b + 10 c + d$$
and solve for $d$:
$$d = -\frac{10\left(bc+10ac-c-10b-100a\right)}{b+10a-1}.$$
Dividing the numerator by the denominator leaves a remainder of $100$, so $(10a+b-1) \mid 100$. You can take it from there, I bet.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I'll use the line to indicate the base-10 representation of the number rather than the product. Consider the thousands digit: on the left-hand side, you know it is equal to the first digit of $\overline{ac}$, plus a possible carry. This should help with some of the case work.

Additionally, taking both sides modulo 5 tells you something helpful about $b$ as well.

Edit: Missed an easy one: $100(\overline{ab}) = \overline{ab00} \leq \overline{abcd}$. So $\frac{\overline{abcd}}{\overline{ab}}$ can't have 2 digits. In fact, we only have equality in the case where $\overline{cd} = 00$, which gives the trivial solution $0000$.

Comment: Sorry, I've read too fast :)

Comment: @Riley understandable, with the notation. I'll fix it real quick.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this problem has a solution: 
consider the 2 positive integers  $x,y$ that satisfy: 
$$
100x + y = xy \\
100x = y(x-1)
$$
looking at the above equation you can see that $x|y(x-1)$ but $x$ and $x-1$ are coprime so $x|y \Rightarrow y=kx \: k \in \mathbb{N}$ and I can rewrite the equations and get: 
$$
100=k(x-1) \\
y=kx \\
\therefore y>100
$$
this is a contradiction since $y$ has 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

$ab*cd = abcd= 100ab + cd \implies$

$cd = 100 + \frac {cd}{ab} > 100$.

So $cd$ is not a two digit number.

No solution.

(I'm embarrassed to admit I spent an hour on the answer below:)

=========

$(10a +b)(10c + d) = 100ac + (bc+ad)10 + bd = 1000a + 100b + 10c + d$

So $bd \equiv d \mod 10$

So $bd \equiv d \mod 2$.

And $bd \equiv d \mod 5$.

So either $d \equiv 0 \mod 2,5$ and/or $b \equiv 1 \mod 2,5$.

Case 1:  $b \equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $b \equiv 1 \mod 5$. i.e. $b = 6$.

$100ac + (6c+ad)10 + 6d = 1000a + 600 + 10c + d$

$10ac + 6c + ad + d/2 = 100a + 60 + c$

So $d \equiv 0 \mod 2$. And $6c + ad + d/2 \equiv c \mod 10$

So $d/2 \equiv c \mod 2$  and $\frac d2(2a +1) \equiv 0 \mod 5$

So either $\frac d2\equiv 0 \mod 5$ which would mean $d = 0$. Or $2a+1$ is a multiple of $5$ which would mean $a = 2, 7$.

Case 1a) $b = 6; d=0; c$ is even.

$(10a +6)(10c ) = 100ac + 60c = 1000a + 600 + 10c$

$10ac + 5c = 100a + 30$

$c = \frac {20a + 6}{2a + 1}= 10 - \frac 4{2a+1}$.

$a \ne d = 0$ but that is the only possible solution.

Case 1b:$b = 6; d\ne 0;a = 2$

$26(10c + d) = 260c + 26d = 2600 + 10c + d$

$25(10c+d) = 2600$

$10c + d = 104$ which is impossible.

Case 1c) $b = 2; d\ne 0; a = 7$

$76(10c + d) = 760c +76d = 7600 + 10c + d$

$75(10c+d) = 7600$

$10c + d = 101 \frac 13$ which is impossible.

Case 2:  $d \equiv 0 \mod 5$ and $d \equiv 0 \mod 5$ i.e. $d = 0$.

Then

$10c(10a + b) = 100ac + 10bc = 1000a + 100b + 10c$

$c(10a + b - 1) = 100a + 10b = 10*(10a +b -1) +10$

$c = 10 + \frac 1{10a + b -1}$ which is impossible.

Case 3:  $d = 0\mod 5; d\equiv 1 \mod 2$ and $b \equiv 1 \mod 2$.  i.e $d =1$ and $b = 2k+1$

$(10c +1)(10a + b) = 100ac + (a+bc)10 + b = 1000a + 100b + 10c + 1$ so $b =1 = d$ which is impossible.

So Case 4: $d \equiv 0 \mod 2; d\not \equiv 0 \mod 5$ and $b \equiv 1 \mod 5; b \ne 6$.  ie $b = 1$ and $d \ne 0$.

$(10c + d)(10a + 1) = 100ac + 10(ad +c) + d = 1000a + 100 + 10c + d$

$10ac + ad + c = 100a + 10 +c$

$10ac + ad = 100a +10$

$a = 0, 5$ but $a$ cannot be $0$ as $abcd$ and $ab$ are proper 4 and two digit numbers.

So $a = 5$ and $50c + 5d = 510$ so $10c + d = 102$.

There is no solution where $a,b,c,d$ are distinct.